# Efficient way to compare two lists in Python (converting from R code)

Tags: python, r

I'm working on writing a transition matrix calculator for genomic data. I have two lists of SNPs: `previousState` and `currentState`. I also have a list of the unique nucleotides found in my file: `uniqueSNPs`.

I'm trying to convert this nested for loop in R:

`for (i in 1 : nstate)
  {
    totalNucleotides = sum(previousState == uniqueSNPs[i])
    for (j in 1 : nstate)
    {
      matches = sum(previousState == uniqueSNPs[i] & 
                  previousState == uniqueSNPs[j])
      tran.mat[i, j] = matches / totalNucleotides
    }
  }`

where `nstate` is just the length of `uniqueSNPs`.

I have everything squared away except for the calculation of `matches` in Python. My approach thus far:

```
for i in range(0, len(uniqueSNPs)):
    totalNucleotides = previousState.count(uniqueSNPs[i])
    for j in range(0, len(uniqueSNPs)):
        matches = sum((previousState == uniqueSNPs[i]) & 
            (currentState == uniqueSNPs[j]))
        mat[i,j] = matches / totalNucleotides
```

However, I get an error on the line where `matches` is calculated that says
`TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable`.
I was wondering if there was a way to write this line of code in a concise and efficient performing manner in Python? I'm relatively new to Python programming so I'm unaware of any nice tricks.

Thanks!

Comment: you cannot do global operations on python lists as they may contain anything. Either you build an inner loop on the list elements, either you use the numpy Library to convert this list into an array that support vectorized actions. The latter is a little more complex but give you far better performances.

Comment: To complement Vince's comment: the comparison `previousState == uniqueSNPs[i]`  and other do not produce iterable vectors as they would in R, they produce boolean scalars.